# EmberJS is not loading up the model correctly

Tags: javascript, ember.js

At a loss on this one.

I'm using Ember and Ember data. I've got this extra implementation of ic-ajax to make GET, POST and PUT calls. Anyway, i'm trying to make a GET call then turn those results into model instances.

```
return this.GET('/editor')
    .then((data) => {
            return data.drafts.map((draftData) => {
                let draft = this.store.find('draft',draftData.id);
                console.log(draft.get('type'));
                return draft;
            });
    });
```

My API returns proper data as `data.drafts`.  This map is supposed to return an array of promises that resolve to `draft` models. It does not. It resolves to a `draft` model that has `id`, `date`, and `title`. But that's it.  I have 25 others attributions.

In another part of the application i'm getting drafts using `findAll` on the model. And those models look fine. But when I try `store.findRecord('draft',id)` i get these fake objects.

-- edit

This is what my ReOpenClass method looks like for getting an array of objects from the server and turning them into ember objects

```
search(critera) {
    let query = { search: critera };
    let adapter = this.store.adapterFor('application');
    let url = adapter.buildURL('article','search');
    return adapter.ajax(url,'GET', { data: query }).then(response => {
        let articleRecords = response.articles.map((article) => {
            let record;
            try {
                record = this.store.createRecord('article', article);
            } catch(e) {
                record = this.store.peekRecord('article', article.id);
            }
            return record;
        });
        return articleRecords;
    });
},
```

So far I can't find a better way to pull this off.

Comment: Do you see many GET '/draft/:id' requests in browser tools and what are response payload for them? Also provide ember and ember-data versions, please.

Comment: just 1 request, in which the payload is `{drafts:[...]}`. Ember 1.12.1 Ember Data 1.13.5

Comment: That isn't the correct payload for a single record, it should be `{ draft: {...} }`

Comment: The payload is supposed to be many records, not just 1. The data back from the server is perfect. and the find call returns what you mentioned.

Comment: Can you post your adapter code?

Comment: @ChristopherMilne not sure what you're asking for, we're using the Rest adapter.

Comment: Why aren't you using the adapter to load your data?

Comment: b/c the adapter AFIK doesn't have a way to do more than 1 findAll type. This call needs to get drafts, but not all drafts. So it should call a diff method.  I could use query() but that overloads the main GET /drafts call with all this query parsing instead of getting all drafts.